# Error - TypeError: expect(...).toHaveValue is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, fixtures, jasmine-jquery

I am just learning and trying to test my javascript with Jasmine framework. My javascript is just setting placeholder attribute of textarea to blank.

```
function clearPlaceholderTextOnFocus(i) {
    i.placeholder = '';
}
```

I am calling this function on onClick event of textarea. I wrote below code in Jasmine spec-

```
describe("Test suite for clearPlaceholderTextOnFocus",function(){
it("Should set placeholder to blank", function(){

var i=affix('textarea[name="message"][placeholder="write your message here..."]');

clearPlaceholderTextOnFocus(i);

var placeholderval = $('i').attr('placeholder'); 
expect(placeholderval).toHaveValue('');
});

});
```

When I run this code by double clicking on SpecRunner.html then I am getting below error -

TypeError: expect(...).toHaveValue is not a function

I have also tried - expect(placeholderval).toEqual("");
but then I get this error - Expected undefined to equal ''.

Below is my SpecRunner.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.5.2</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/boot.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine-fixture.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script src="src/myfirst.js"></script> 

  <!-- include spec files here...  -->
  <script src="spec/myfirstSpec.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with my spec code? How I can get value of placeholder so that I can check if that is blank now.

Answer (score 0):

`expect().toHaveValue()` is not a valid jasmine selector. instead you can use `expect().toContain()` to check if is sting or array conatins a particular value.

you have also mentioned that you are also facing the below `Expected undefined to equal ''`.This is because the value of the variable `placeholder` is undefined. but you are asserting the value of placeholder to be an empty string.

Comment: How I can get value of attribute 'placeholder' from textarea after my function gets executed?

Comment: Thanks it worked for me with some changes. Your answer was useful